# JWT authentication always returns 401 unauthorized

Tags: laravel, axios, jwt

I am implementing JWT token for my laravel 6 project. I have followed this tutorial and successfully configured the application to use JWT. I am also able to login using `auth()->attempt($credentials)` which returns the JWT token.

Now when I try to access any other api route and send jwt token in request header for authorization, it always returns `401 (Unauthorized)`.

Here is my code

**api.php**

```
Route::group([

    'prefix' => 'auth'

], function ($router) {

    Route::post('login', 'Auth\React\RAuthController@login');
    Route::post('get_user_pages', 'Auth\React\RAuthController@getUserPages');

});
```

**axios request**

```
const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/get_user_pages', {}, {
     headers: {"Authorization": `Bearer ${cookie.load('token')}`}
})
.then(function (response) {
     console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
     console.log(error);
});
```

**Controller function**

```
public function getUserPages()
{
    $auth_user_id = auth()->id();

    $user_role_id = User::find($auth_user_id)->roles->makeHidden('pivot')->pluck('id')->first();

    return $user_pages = ROLE::find($user_role_id)->pages->toArray();
}
```

I don't understand when I am able to access login route then why not other routes?

Comment: I am having the same issue, any luck finding the solution? For me it started recently

Answer (score 1):

Try editing the route

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'api',
    'prefix' => 'auth'

], function ($router) {

    Route::post('login', 'Auth\React\RAuthController@login');
    Route::post('get_user_pages', 'Auth\React\RAuthController@getUserPages');

});
```

Inside`config/auth.php` file:

```
'guards' => [
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Comment: Are you using tymondesigns/jwt-auth package? Did you generated secret key? Did you implemented User model to JWTSubject?

Comment: You can try using driver:`jwt` and middleware `jwt.auth` and also try to dump `auth('api')->user()` under jwt middleware